# Finding the perimeter of an equilateral triangle given height

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given an equilateral triangle with vertices $A,B,C$, find the perimeter of the triangle if the height of this triangle is $8\sqrt{6}$.

I do not have a visual image for this problem, because I cannot see. However, this shape is not complex, and I think it is really not needed here.

When I first attempted this problem, I imagined an altitude $\overline{DE}$ being drawn from one of the vertices to the base forming a right angle. I also think that the height is equal to the altitude. This creates two right triangles and I now can apply trigonometric ratio to solve for the hypotenuse. I think $\sin$ will be a good choice, since I want to get the hypotenuse:
$$\sin {A} = \frac{8\sqrt{6}}{h}$$
Since this is an equalatteral triangle, all of its angle is $60^\circ$. Therefore, I can safely assume that $A$ is also $60^\circ$.

By chance, I also know that $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is equal to $\sin{60}$. Substituting the values into the equation, I get
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{8\sqrt{6}}{h}$$
Solving this, I found that the length of the hypotenuse is of $\triangle ADE$ is $16\sqrt{2}$. Since the question asks for the perimeter, the answer is $48\sqrt{2}$. But my teacher does not agree with my solution. She insists that the answer is $24\sqrt{2}$.

I really do not understand why I am wrong. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: You're correct :).

Comment: I got the same answer as you, so I agree with dmk's comment that you're correct.

Comment: Think of it this way:  The height is $8\sqrt{6} \approx 19.6$.  The supposed perimeter is $24\sqrt{2} \approx 33.9$.  But the altitude drops down from an angle formed by two sides, each of which must have length at least $8\sqrt{6}$.  So the perimeter is already well over $24\sqrt{2}$, with only two sides accounted for.

Comment: Perhaps the teacher is unconsciously referring to to the semiperimeter which is used in many important formulas?

Comment: @user, I do not think so. I think she is very contious of what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The height of the equilateral triangle splits the triangle into 2 30$^\circ$-60$^\circ$-90$^\circ$ triangles.  In these special right triangles, the hypotenuse is twice the length of the short leg, and the long leg is the length of the short leg times $\sqrt{3}$.  This means $|\overline{AM}| = \frac{8\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $|\overline{AC}|$ is twice this length or $\frac{16\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{3}}$.  The perimeter of the equilateral triangle triangle is 3 times this length, which is $\frac{48\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{3}} \approx$ 67.88un.  Which is also 48$\sqrt{2}$ so you are correct.

Comment: What does your "un$^2$" suffix mean?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it to un for units.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I have never seen "un" used as an abbreviation for "units", although it's listed in [UN means Units](https://www.allacronyms.com/UN/Units). Nonetheless, as shown in that link, you should use a capitalized version of it, i.e., "UN", to help make it more clear that it's not a product of $2$ variables, i.e., $u$ and $n$. Also, since I don't think it's a very commonly used abbreviation, you should perhaps either generally avoid having anything at all there (as it's not required), just use the full "units", or add a brief explanation.